# Merge duplicate rows and delete all duplicates after merging into one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple duplicate IDs as such:

```
 id                col1          col2      col3
ENE80R             N             N         Y
ENE80R             N             N         N
ENE80R             Y             N         N
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
 id                col1          col2      col3
ENE80R              Y             N         Y
```

I tried using df.drop_duplicates but it doesn't update all the Ys into one column, it just keeps the first row and removes the duplicates. Any idea how I can go about this?

EDIT: The data doesn't only contain Y and N in it, there are columns that contain data and other text and integer data. But the only data that differ in the duplicated data are the Ys and Ns.

Comment: Without giving us sample data that reflects your problem set, how do you expect us to understand how to solve your problem.  It ends up wasting people's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to replace `'Y'` for `True` and `'N'` for `False` then do a `groupby` with `any`.  Finally, clean it up by reversing the replace.

```
df.replace(dict(Y=True, N=False)) \
  .groupby('id').any() \
  .replace({True: 'Y', False: 'N'})

       col1 col2 col3
id                   
ENE80R    Y    N    Y
```

Alternatively, you could use `pd.DataFrame.any` with the `level` parameter.

```
df.set_index('id').eq('Y').any(level=0).replace({True: 'Y', False: 'N'})

       col1 col2 col3
id                   
ENE80R    Y    N    Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple max by groupby since Y is greater than N. i.e

```
df.groupby('id').max()

      col1 col2 col3
id                   
ENE80R    Y    N    Y
```

Or Thanks @pirSquared:

```
df.set_index('id').max(level=0)
```

Comment: or `df.set_index('id').max(level=0)` (-: